# Regex code , Python-2 alphanumeric

Tags: regex, python-2.7

a="abc PYTHON12 ab ahb67 elf 5678 abdc"

I need to write a regular expression such that only the alphanumeric gets replaced while the text and numbers remain intact.

I have used 
re.sub(r'\w+\d','xx', a)

but it replaces all the alphanumeric as well as numbers
present output:- 'abc xx ab xx elf xx abdc'
Required output:- 'abc xx ab xx elf 5678 abdc'

Comment: If you are still struggling with it, [here is a demo](https://ideone.com/EDyIRk) with the solution in the dupe reason. I just removed what you do not need (`\S*`, `_` and `-`)

Comment: @Wiktor it worked. !! Thanks.